# Assign variable with the value returned from chain of function calls

Tags: python

I would like to assign some value a function returned if the value is not `None` to variable, or else assign different value, or yet another different value...
I only want to call the function once.

I currently use `try` and `except TypeError`, but only works for two options and is not very clean.

```
try:
    value = someFunction()["content"]
except KeyError:
    value = someOtherFunction()["content"]
```

Comment: Those are dictionaries right?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes, specifically BeautifulSoup result

Comment: is `someFunction()["content"]` actually `None`or is there just no "content" field in the dictionnary?

Comment: `value = f(something) or g(something)` ;)

Comment: @bouletta the variable is supposed to be dictionary and when is None, it throws `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` so the except block executes

Comment: Ok so not a 'KeyError`then

Comment: I agreed with @Kevin except that `someOtherFunction()['content']` may result into the same issue, maybe have a default value to return when key 'content' is not in the dict

Comment: @Mitch wouldn't that make value a boolean?

Comment: @bouletta No. It's not a good solution though (truthiness != not None), just a bit amusing.

Comment: @Mitch yeah just tried it out I didn't know about that. I thought it would evaluate `f(something) or g(something)` and put the result in `value`. Pretty cool trick though!

Comment: @Mitch the `or` method looks very good, but doesn't work for me since it throws exception because it's still trying to find ["content"] in None

Comment: @bouletta yes, you are right, fixed :)

Answer (score 3):

Since the value returned is of type `dict`, you may use `dict.get` to achieve the same behavior in one-line as:

```
value = someFunction().get("content", someOtherFunction()["content"])
```

But this will be applicable if you are dealing with only two values as mentioned in the question. For dealing with chain of multiple functions, you may create a list of function and check for the "key" in the returned dict object as:

```
my_functions = [func1, func2, func3]

for func in my_functions:
    returned_val = func()
    if 'content' in returned_val:  # checks for 'content' key in returned `dict`
        value = returned_val['content']
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
def try_run(func_list, field, default_value):
  for f in func_list:
    try:
      value = f()[field]
      return value
    except (TypeError, KeyError):
      pass
  return default_value

try_run([someFunction, someOtherFunction], 'content', 'no content')
```

[Sample Code](https://repl.it/Fmgl)

Answer (score 1):

This requires an external library but you could use [`iteration_utilities.first`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/first.html):

```
from iteration_utilities import first

# The logic that you want to execute for each function (it's the same for each function, right?)
def doesnt_error(func):
    try:
        return func()['content']
    except (KeyError, TypeError):
        return False

# some sample functions
func1 = lambda: None
func2 = lambda: {}
func3 = lambda: {'content': 'what?'}

# A tuple containing all functions that should be tested.
functions = (func1, func2, func3)

# Get the first result of the predicate function 
# the `retpred`-argument ensures the function is only called once.
value = first(functions, pred=doesnt_error, retpred=True)
```

---

<sup>1 This is from a third-party library I have written: [`iteration_utilities`](https://github.com/MSeifert04/iteration_utilities).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
value = someFunction()["content"] if ("content" in someFunction() and someFunction()["content"] != None) else someOtherFunction()["content"]
```

Although with this someFunction is going to be called potentially multiple times so you might want to add

```
d = someFunction()
```

before and replace someFunction() by d in the oneliner

Comment: you still have the KeyError exception probably bound to happen

Comment: `value = someFunction()["content"] if "content" in someFunction else do_something`

Comment: @Gigapalmer well hence my comment on the question. If "content" is for sure in the dict then there would not be a `KeyError`. Otherwise I agree

Answer (score 0):

If someFunction returns a dictionary, you can use

```
dict_object = someFunction()
if 'content' in dict_object.keys() and dict_object['content'] is not None:
    value = dict_object['content']
else:
    value = someOtherFunction['content']
```

Comment: By the way, the first one was way better. but `'content' in dict_object.keys()` is a bit slower compare to `'content' in dict_object` since calling keys() will return the entire list of keys.

I prefer --> `'content' in dict_object`